# Binding points in chart control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, charts, microsoft-chart-controls

I have a Chart Control that I am trying to dynamically populate with a number of series from a sqldatasource, here's my chart control:

```
<asp:Chart ID="chartMonthly" runat="server" Width="920px" ImageLocation="~/Images/Temp/ChartPic_#SEQ(300,3)" Palette="Berry">
        <ChartAreas>
            <asp:ChartArea Name="line"></asp:ChartArea>
        </ChartAreas>
    </asp:Chart>
```

And here's how I dynamically add the series and points:

```
Private Sub chartMonthly_DataBinding(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles chartMonthly.DataBinding

    Dim conStr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("GenshenPOS").ConnectionString
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection(conStr)

    conn.Open()

    Dim sqlPoints As New SqlCommand("SELECT [m] AS [月], [Store] AS [門市], SUM([amount]) AS [NTD] FROM vwMonthly WHERE [y] = " & dropYear.SelectedValue & " GROUP BY [m], [Store]", conn)

    Dim reader As SqlDataReader = sqlPoints.ExecuteReader()

    While reader.Read()

        If chartMonthly.Series.IndexOf(reader.Item("門市")) = -1 Then

            chartMonthly.Series.Add(reader.Item("門市"))
            chartMonthly.Legends.Add(reader.Item("門市"))
            chartMonthly.Series(reader.Item("門市")).ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line
            chartMonthly.Series(reader.Item("門市")).ChartArea = "line"

        End If

        chartMonthly.Series(reader.Item("門市")).Points.AddXY("月", "NTD")

    End While

    conn.Close()

End Sub
```

The chart is reading the names of the stores correctly and creating series based on them, but my chart is empty of data - none of the axis have values and the lines for the series go across the bottom of the chart as 0/Null values.

I've run the underlying query separately and the data is there, and I assume its seeing the data otherwise the series and legends would not be created, so I assume I'm missing something from the way I add points to the series?!

[Image of chart control with series but displaying no datapoints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NGGz.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding Points.AddXY by explicitly casting to datetime (first of the month)

```
chartMonthly.Series(reader.Item("門市")).Points.AddXY(New DateTime(Integer.Parse(dropYear.SelectedValue), Integer.Parse(reader("月").ToString()), 1), "NTD")
```